# Add to dataGridView by C# code

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to add every time counter increases new row by using new BindingSource 
but it adds on row "the last modified"

This is my code:

```
     public class PacketWrapper
    {
        public string p;

        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string Timeval { get { return "l"; } }
        public string LinkLayerType { get { return"2"; } }
        public int Length { get { return p.Length; } }

        public PacketWrapper(int count, string p)
        {
            this.Count = count;
            this.p = p;
        }
    }
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    PacketWrapper p;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        p = new PacketWrapper(1, "djd");

        Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = (450); // 45 mins
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);

        MyTimer.Start();

    }

    private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            p.Count = i;

            bs.DataSource = p;

        }
    }
```

How Can I add every time new row using this code??

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
bs.DataSource = p;
```

with

```
bs.Add(p);
```